# How to create a query to combine two or three rows for duplicated IDs

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a select statement to combine values from duplicated IDs on any specific columns.

My table is:

```
ID   Name
---------
01   A
01   B
02   C
03   D
```

How can I select to get values like: 01 A, B for ID: 01. Currently, when I use Select * from Tablename, it lists 01 ID for two rows. I like to combine it into one row only, Name should be combined with a comma for any duplicated rows.

New code:

```
select Name, ID = REPLACE
  ((select Surname AS [data()]
        FROM Mytable
        WHERE Name = d. Name
        ORDER BY Name FOR XML path('')), ' ', REQUIRED SEPERATOR)
FROM Mytable d
WHERE Name IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY Name
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: I am using SQL Server. Thanks.

Comment: there is no `group_concat`-like operator in SQLServer, so you can not do that directly, but there are methods to achieve this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simulating group\_concat MySQL function in Microsoft SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005)

Comment: I tried that method as this above, but it says Incorrect syntacx near 'Seperator', Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't it be "SEP**A**RATOR" ?

Comment: I changed the letter E to A, it says the same error.

Comment: @jenny try `','` instead of `REQUIRED SEPARATOR`, it is just placeholder for actual separator character

Comment: No more error. But the result is not right. ID column now shows all names, separated with comma, like A, B, A, B, A, B. It is supposed to show 01. Thanks.

Comment: @JennyTran posted full working example in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/56a9a/3)

**MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup**:

```
create table t (id int not null, name nvarchar(max) not null)
insert t (id, name) values 
  (1, 'A'), 
  (1, 'B'),
  (1, 'C'), 
  (2, 'A'),
  (2, 'D'), 
  (3, 'A'),
  (3, 'F'), 
  (3, 'E')
```

**Query 1**:

```
    select id, REPLACE
      ((select name AS [data()]
            FROM t as t1
            WHERE t1.id = t0.id
            ORDER BY Name FOR XML path('')), ' ', ',')
    FROM t as t0
    GROUP BY id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/56a9a/3/0)**:

```
| id |       |
|----|-------|
|  1 | A,B,C |
|  2 |   A,D |
|  3 | A,E,F |
```

**UPDATE**
To deal with spaces already in names, we can replace them to underscores, before grouping, and replace back after:

```
  select id, replace(REPLACE
  ((select replace(name, ' ', '_') AS [data()]
        FROM t as t1
        WHERE t1.id = t0.id
        ORDER BY Name FOR XML path('')), ' ', ','), '_', ' ')
FROM t as t0
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: Only one small issue. If column name has two or more words like 'A B', or 'A B C', then every space was changed to a comma. How do I fix that? Thanks.

Comment: you can replace spaces to, for example, underscores before concatenating, and replace back after

Comment: Perfect. Thanks very much!